# How to get the width and height of the active monitor?

Tags: autohotkey

```
#singleinstance, force
#Warn, All, OutputDebug

space::
Gui HUD:New, +AlwaysOnTop +ToolWindow -Caption +HwndMainHwnd, hudWin
Gui HUD:Font,s14,Consolas
Gui, Add, Text,,% Clipboard
GuiControlGet, OutputVar, Pos, Static1
Gui HUD:Show

Return
```

The above is a simple program that is meant to show display the current text in my clipboard. Its not important I am just using it to learn more about GUIs. One thing I cant seem to figure out is how to spawn the GUI on the centre of the active monitor rather than the primary monitor (I have 3 monitors)

According to the docs `A_ScreenWidth` and `A_ScreenHeight` is for the "Primary" monitor. Also looking at [SysGet](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v1/lib/SysGet.htm), its mostly about "Primary" monitor or monitor 2. Which does not mean much.

I want to create dynamic `x`,`y`, `width` and `height` values for  use in the `Gui HUD:Show` sub command. This way the GUI will always spawns on the monitor that has the active window or keyboard focus.

Also I am assuming by "primary" monitor, the monitor that has the taskbar and start button is what is being referred to.

I searched quite a bit and surprisingly there was not much on this. Am I over looking something?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a function that finds monitor info, given a coordinate:

```
#Requires AutoHotkey v2.0

ScreenUtil_GetMonitorInfoAtPoint(x, y, &monitorIndex, &left, &top, &right, &bottom){
    loop MonitorGetCount(){
        MonitorGet(A_Index, &_left, &_top, &_right, &_bottom)
        if(_left <= x && x <= _right && _top <= y && y <= _bottom){
            monitorIndex := A_Index
            left := _left
            top := _top
            right := _right
            bottom := _bottom
            return
        }
    }
    throw Error("Cannot find a monitor that encloses the point!")
}
```

Then, depending on how you define "active monitor":

1. To get info of the monitor which the **active window** resides in:

```
ScreenUtil_GetMonitorInfoOfActiveWindow(&monitorIndex, &left, &top, &right, &bottom){
    WinGetPos(&mx, &my, &mw, &mh, "A")
    ScreenUtil_GetMonitorInfoAtPoint(mx + mw//2, my + mh//2, &monitorIndex, &left, &top, &right, &bottom)
}

ScreenUtil_GetMonitorInfoOfActiveWindow(&monitorIndex, &left, &top, &right, &bottom)
MsgBox("Width: " right - left "`nHeight: " bottom - top)
```

2. To get info of the monitor which the **mouse pointer** resides in :

```
ScreenUtil_GetMonitorInfoAtMousePointer(&monitorIndex, &left, &top, &right, &bottom){
    CoordMode "Mouse", "Screen"
    MouseGetPos(&mx, &my)
    ScreenUtil_GetMonitorInfoAtPoint(mx, my, &monitorIndex, &left, &top, &right, &bottom)
}

ScreenUtil_GetMonitorInfoAtMousePointer(&monitorIndex, &left, &top, &right, &bottom)
MsgBox("Width: " right - left "`nHeight: " bottom - top)
```

---

(Combined script for testing)

```
#Requires AutoHotkey v2.0

!1::{
    ScreenUtil_GetMonitorInfoOfActiveWindow(&monitorIndex, &left, &top, &right, &bottom)
    MsgBox("Width: " right - left "`nHeight: " bottom - top)
}

!2::{
    ScreenUtil_GetMonitorInfoAtMousePointer(&monitorIndex, &left, &top, &right, &bottom)
    MsgBox("Width: " right - left "`nHeight: " bottom - top)
}

ScreenUtil_GetMonitorInfoOfActiveWindow(&monitorIndex, &left, &top, &right, &bottom){
    WinGetPos(&mx, &my, &mw, &mh, "A")
    ScreenUtil_GetMonitorInfoAtPoint(mx + mw//2, my + mh//2, &monitorIndex, &left, &top, &right, &bottom)
}

ScreenUtil_GetMonitorInfoAtMousePointer(&monitorIndex, &left, &top, &right, &bottom){
    CoordMode "Mouse", "Screen"
    MouseGetPos(&mx, &my)
    ScreenUtil_GetMonitorInfoAtPoint(mx, my, &monitorIndex, &left, &top, &right, &bottom)
}

ScreenUtil_GetMonitorInfoAtPoint(x, y, &monitorIndex, &left, &top, &right, &bottom){
    loop MonitorGetCount(){
        MonitorGet(A_Index, &_left, &_top, &_right, &_bottom)
        if(_left <= x && x <= _right && _top <= y && y <= _bottom){
            monitorIndex := A_Index
            left := _left
            top := _top
            right := _right
            bottom := _bottom
            return
        }
    }
    throw Error("Cannot find a monitor that encloses the point!")
}
```